# awk edit only 1 column with regex

Tags: regex, awk

I have a CSV file with 3 columns:

```
id,text,date
123,hi 你好吗？,2016-01-01
246,this is stackoverflow 我需要帮忙,2016-02-01
```

I want to only edit column 2 where i remove only english characters and keep the chinese ones. The other columns remain untouched.

Output i want:

```
id,text,date
123,你好吗？,2016-01-01
246,我需要帮忙,2016-02-01
```

Is there a better way to do it than this:

```
cat myfile.csv|cut -d, -f2|sed 's/[a-zA-Z]*//g' > tmp.csv
paste -d, myfile.csv tmp.csv|awk -F, '{OFS=",";print $1,$7,$3}' >tmp2.csv
```

Comment: If the English characters are only in 2nd column then [this](https://regex101.com/r/bI0pZ0/2) shall work .`\b[a-z ]+\b`. After matching you can replace them with `nothing`.

Comment: edited code to add my regex

Comment: @jxn: Check my demo.

Comment: @noob posting a regexp and showing it do something in some online tool is not useful. Given the large variety of regexp varieties and tool-specific expansions and constraints, a regexp is only useful in the context of the tool you expect to use it in.

Comment: @EdMorton That's true. But giving a demo using online tool at least setup on some path of certainty. I find it useful. And it was a comment not a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} { if (NR>1) {gsub(/[\x00-\x7F]/, "", $2)}; print }' test.txt
```

- `NR>1`: don't operate on first line
- `gsub(/[\x00-\x7F]/, "", $2)`: get rid of ascii characters in column 2. [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: This would remove any punctuation, etc., if it used an ASCII value <= 0x7F.  Also, why use `","` in the print instead of `OFS=","`?

Comment: Might as well replace `print $1,$2,$3` by `print`.

Comment: Works well with GNU Awk and Mawk, but, curiously, to make it work with BSD Awk (as also found on OS X), `\x00` must be replaced with `\x01`.

Answer (score 2):

If the script you posted at the bottom of your question works for you then so will this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/,"",$2)} 1' file
```

You said "characters" though, not "letters", so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{ s=split($2,t," "); sub($2, t[s]); print }' file
id,text,date
123,你好吗？,2016-01-01
246,我需要帮忙,2016-02-01
```

Comment: This blindly replaces the 2nd field with its last space-separated token. It happens to work for the sample data given, but is not a generic solution.

Comment: Please explain, how your solution works / what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1{print;}NR>1{gsub(/[a-zA-Z ]+/,"");print;}' your_file
id,text,date
123,你好吗？,2016-01-01
246,我需要帮忙,2016-02-01
```

Comment: You're replacing English letters and spaces in _all_ fields, whereas the OP asked for the 2nd field specifically. If you fix that, however, you'll end up having duplicated Ed Morton's answer (except for also removing _spaces_).